# 'python setup.py bdist' gets error on 'compiler_flags'

Tags: python, windows, python-3.6

On **Windows 2016** and following official documents, I've successfully [compiled source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/PCbuild/readme.txt) of ***Python-3.6.12***. When trying to [build distribution](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/builtdist.html), I got the following error complaining about *compiler_flags*.

Also notice that this is from compiling source code, and command `python` actually calls `python.bat` in the main directory.

Just let me know if you need more details, and any help or pointers will be highly appreciated.

**Screenshot:** 
(python version and exception traceback, from CMD)

```
D:\Python\Python36>python -V
Running Release|x64 interpreter...
Python 3.6.12

D:\Python\Python36>python setup.py bdist
Running Release|x64 interpreter...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 29, in <module>
set_compiler_flags('CFLAGS', 'PY_CFLAGS_NODIST')
File "setup.py", line 27, in set_compiler_flags
sysconfig.get_config_vars()[compiler_flags] = flags + ' ' + py_flags_nodist
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

D:\Python\Python36>
```

A little more information: 
I've now installed pip, setuptools, wheel, and added to Path the directories of "D:\Python\Python36" and "D:\Python\Python36". But the error on bdist stays the same. I'm new to Python source code release, so thank you for your help and patience.

**Screenshots:**

```
D:\Python\Python36>python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel
Running Release|x64 interpreter...
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in d:\python\python36\lib\site-packages (50.1.0)
Requirement already up-to-date: wheel in d:\python\python36\lib\site-packages (0.35.1)

...
D:\Python\Python36>python setup.py bdist
Running Release|x64 interpreter...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ... the same error as before ...
```

Comment: try:  `pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel`

Comment: Thank you, @KetZoomer, I've installed pip, setuptools, and wheel, following your hints, and it helps a little bit. But the error still says on bdist.

Comment: can you show us your setup.py

Comment: Could you please see [setup.py on the official github repo](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/setup.py)? I've compared, it's identical with my local instance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you made an error when trying to add a 'NoneType' value and a 'str' value. If those are values that you would like to concatenate, then you should use:

```
variable = ''.join(value 1, value 2)
```

Comment: Hi @balexander1, The error message says "File "setup.py", line 27, in set_compiler_flags", and file setup.py comes with Python-3.6.12.tgz from [official source release](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3612/). Do you mean to modify file setup.py?